# How to dynamically set a doughnut chart size in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have been racking my brain to fix this issue. For reasons I cannot figure out, the doughnut charts are displaying really tiny. So, I have a bunch of charts that I am generating on the fly and stacking them next to each other. **I am** setting the chart dimensions on the fly, but there is so much empty space inside the border of the chart that can be used to make the doughnut bigger. I am enclosing some additional details below:

What I have right now:
[image]

What I want:

[image]

This is the code that I have:

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Const numChartsPerRow = 3
Const TopAnchor As Long = 8
Const LeftAnchor As Long = 380
Const HorizontalSpacing As Long = 3
Const VerticalSpacing As Long = 3
Const ChartHeight As Long = 125
Const ChartWidth As Long = 210
Counter = 0

For Each zChartSet In ws.ChartObjects
    zChartSet.Delete
Next zChartSet

While j <= iTeamMemberCount
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlDoughnut).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Analytics Team Stats").Range("E" & j & ":F" & j)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""series1"""
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}" 
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    Selection.Caption = Split(Worksheets("Analytics Team Stats").Range("A" & j), ",")(1) & " - " & Format(Worksheets("Analytics Team Stats").Range("E" & j), "0%")
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Explosion = 15
    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).DoughnutHoleSize = 55
     
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.0500000007
        .Solid
    End With
    
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.5
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = Worksheets("Analytics Team Stats").Range("A" & j)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = Worksheets("Analytics Team Stats").Range("E" & j & ":F" & j)
     
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
     
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Points(1).Select
    Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
     
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Points(2).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.0500000007
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Transparency = 0.1999999881
        .Solid
    End With
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendNone)
    
    j=j+1
    wend
```

Comment: ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).DoughnutHoleSize = 30 . Play with this value to meet what you need

Comment: I did and it is not resizing the doughnuts, instead, it is created two concentric doughnuts. Where can I add a picture in the reply?

Comment: Sub test()
   ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).DoughnutHoleSize = 10  '20 30 40
End Sub
run this test for one -the active- chart. Responds to value changes?

Comment: It does change the hole size according to the number.

Comment: So since it changes, while in your code it doesn't, it means that some command after ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).DoughnutHoleSize = 55 cancels it or some commands before don't allow it to be set. Comment out pieces of code to find what is negating the value you put in DonutHoleSize.

Comment: So, after making the changes you suggested, I am now having a different problem. Can I accept your answer and share the link to the second question here?

Comment: ok, i have an answer..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253114/discussion-between-jrules80-and--).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automate the ring thickness process, you should think like this: a) Thickness is a function of the smaller of height and width. b) Find the smallest possible width-height value, then test which value of DonutHoleSize is satisfactory. c) Do the same with the smallest of the largest possible height or width. So we will have two pairs of numbers (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) which are read as follows: For the minimum width/height x1 satisfies me for DonutHoleSize the value y1, and for the maximum width/height x2 satisfies me for the DonutHoleSize the value y2.
You can now apply the method of linear interpolation to find a satisfactory value for DonutHoleSize for a width/height >= x1 and <= x2. The formula is as follows:

```
Public Function linear_interpolation(x1 As Double, y1 As Double, x2 As Double, y2 As Double, ByVal x As Double) As Double
   If (x2 - x1) = 0 Then   'division by zero
      linear_interpolation = 0#  'or anything else...maybe y1 or y2 ...
   Else
      linear_interpolation = y1 + (((x - x1) * (y2 - y1)) / (x2 - x1))
   End If
End Function

Function minOf(a As Variant, b As Variant) As Variant
   If (a < b) Then minOf = a Else minOf = b
End Function

'and the usage in code:
ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).DoughnutHoleSize = linear_interpolation(280, 75, 85, 50, minOf(ActiveChart.Chart.ChartArea.Width, ActiveChart.Chart.ChartArea.Height))
```

In my own tests, pairs 280,75 and 85,50  are satisfactory, you can as I described above, adjust them.